# How to bind events dynamically in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

In JSX it's possible to bind multiple events to a DOM element like this:

```html
<input {...inputEvents}>
```

In Svelte, this is done manually.

```html
<input on:input={inputHandler}>
```

This becomes tedious when you need to add multiple handlers (input, blur, focus) to multiple inputs of a form.

The only way I've found to solve this in Svelte is by using refs.

For example:

```html
<input bind:this={myInput}>
```

And then somewhere either do this:

```js
myInput.oninput = (event) => {
  // do something
}
```

Or:

```js
myInput.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // do something
})
```

Is there a better way to bind events dynamically in Svelte?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't :( 

I've came to learn that sveltejs is much less dynamic than expected to be...

Your solution is probably the best way.

Comment: `focusin` and `focusout` bubble while `focus` and `blur` do not ([Focus Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Focus_events)). Have you considered attaching handlers only on the form element and using the [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to route the processing, potentially leaving element specific data in [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)?

Comment: Kind of a workaround, but you could use a `use:` action. Example: https://svelte.dev/repl/6d70347b8b164ce9a0216ca859713655?version=3.20.1

Comment: Hey @PeerReynders that's a great idea!

Comment: Thanks @joshnuss this is great too. More here: https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action

Comment: @joshnuss Does that `destroy` in your `use:` get called when the element is removed from the page?

Comment: @BennyHinrichs yes, `use:` actions call destroy whenever the element is removed from the page. (Unlike `onDestroy`, which called when the component is unmounted)

Comment: say @pier, I'm interested in this as well, what does a full solution look like in JSX? I'm still  learning both react and svelte so I'd love to see your example - do you have a gist handy? if not, no big deal, thx in advance!

Comment: @Paul42 by using the spread operator `{...someEvents}` you can destructure an object. See this simple example: https://gist.github.com/PierBover/f1d233a16cb95724bf0dc9c7e9e3db28

Comment: GH issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5112

Answer (score 8):

If you need to attach the same or similar set of event handlers to various elements then you can use "actions" with `use:action` (ref: https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action )

Here is an example:

```
<script>
  function manyHandlers(element){
    element.addEventListener("click", ev => {...})
    element.addEventListener("focus", ev => {...})
    element.addEventListener("blur", ev => {...})
    ...
  }
</script>

<form>
  <input use:manyHandlers>
  <textarea use:manyHandlers></textarea>
  <!-- and so on... -->
</form>
```

You can pass additional parameters to the function specified in the `use:___`, for example to control which set of event handlers get attached. See the above mentioned documentation reference on how that works.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you can take advantage of event bubbling and attach the event handler to a parent element (eg: the `<form>` element in the above example) and use the `event.target` to do specific handlings with the element that received the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $: before the input handler.

```
<script>
    let myInput = "";

    $: {
        // Do something with myInput
    }
</script>

<body>
    <input type="text" bind:value={myInput}>
</body>
```

It's important to use the "myInput" variable in the eventHandler because it reacts to the state of the variables, used in the function. Also you should bind "value" not "this".